# python crashes with error function takes 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, function, arguments

This works the first time I call the function, but the second time I get the error message

```
mloc = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if type == "gun":
    mTowers.add(gun(mloc))
```

...

```
 class gun(tower):    
     def __init__(self, place):
         tower.__init__(self, place)
```

and the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What I think I'm doing is passing the mouse location as a tuple (and the self argument). Clearly it works on the first call. Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Comment: You should try and avoid using `type` as a variable name, as it's a built-in class.

Answer (score 2):

The `self` is passed implicitly, so you are actually passing in tower, gun (i.e. self), and place respectively.

Also, you should use the [super](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) function here, rather than calling `tower.__init__` explicitly.

Example (python 2.7) of using super:

```
class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self, nlegs=4):
    print 'in __init__ Animal'
    self.nlegs = nlegs

class Cat(Animal):
  def __init__(self, talk='meow'):
    print 'in __init__ Cat'
    super(Cat, self).__init__()
    self.talk = talk

tom = Cat()
print "I'm a cat with {} legs and I say '{}'".format(tom.nlegs, tom.talk)
```

Comment: Oh right, tower is a class.  I missed that because it was lowercase.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the lowercase class name is misleading, isn't it?